# filemtime cannot read file modify time

Tags: php, filemtime

here is my code:

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Baku');
        $dh =opendir('C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\upload\extjs-4.1.1\welcome\css');
        $full_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\upload\extjs-4.1.1\welcome\css';
        $way=array();

        while ($file = readdir($dh)):

         array_push($way,$full_path.$file);
         endwhile;
        closedir($dh);
        echo '<br>';
        for ($t=2;$t<=6;$t++){
       echo "<br> $way[$t] : " . filetype($way[$t]) . "\nCreate Date: " . date("F d Y                       H:i:s ", filemtime((string)$way[$t]) );   

        }


echo '<br>'.date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime('C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\upload\extjs-4.1.1\welcome\css\blank.gif'));

        ?>
```

and this is what it response:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\upload\extjs-4.1.1\welcome\cssblank.gif : Create Date: January 01 1970 00:00:00
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\upload\extjs-4.1.1\welcome\cssiepngfix.htc : Create Date: January 01 1970 00:00:00
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\upload\extjs-4.1.1\welcome\csswelcome.css : Create Date: January 01 1970 00:00:00
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\upload\extjs-4.1.1\welcome\csswelcome_ie6.css : Create Date: January 01 1970 00:00:00
: Create Date: January 01 1970 00:00:00
July 04 2012 16:13:34.`

I think that filemtime cannot read modify time and don't know why.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-$full_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\upload\extjs-4.1.1\welcome\css';
+$full_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\upload\extjs-4.1.1\welcome\css\';
```

You had lost backslash  in full_path variable.
So, you get wrong full path to files:

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\upload\extjs-4.1.1\welcome\csswelcome.css'
```

instead of

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\upload\extjs-4.1.1\welcome\css\welcome.css'
```

Comment: Thanx for fast answer. I'm newbie in this case)